# Monitoring Java process memory utilization

Tags: linux

I have 24 GB RAM on my server(RHEL) and have assigned 2 GB Xmx value to a Java process.

- I need to check if this 2 GB is being consumed completely. Can I check the top command and see if this Java process is consuming 8.3% memory(ie: 2/24) and make an assumption that its using 2 GB at that point. If its less than 8.3%, then I am assuming that it has not reached 2 GB mark. Let me know if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.